# InvalidCastException in OutArgument<T>.Set()

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Strange exception, this was working fine before.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot convert object 'Waiting' to type 'System.Activities.Statements.Pick+PickState'.
   at System.Runtime.TypeHelper.Convert[T](Object source)
   at System.Activities.Location`1.set_ValueCore(Object value)
   at System.Activities.ActivityContext.SetValueCore[T](LocationReference locationReference, T value)
   at System.Activities.ActivityContext.SetValue[T](OutArgument`1 argument, T value)
   at System.Activities.OutArgument`1.Set(ActivityContext context, T value)
   at MyApplication.WaitForStatusChange.OnBookmarkResumed(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, Object value)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.BookmarkCallbackWrapper.Invoke(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, Object value)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.BookmarkWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

MyApplication.WaitForStatusChange is a custom NativeActivity, the error occurs when the workflow is resumed on the bookmark for this activity, whith an enum for bookmar argument.

The WaitForStatusChange activity is placed inside a Pick activity (with another NativeActivity on the other branch)

[image: screeshot]

Activity code

```
  public class WaitForPartnerIntegrationStatusChange : NativeActivity
  {
    public OutArgument<PartnerSoftwareIntegrationStatus> Status { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
      context.CreateBookmark(DocumentStatusChangeWatcher.DocumentPartnerSoftwareIntegrationStatusChangedBookmark, OnBookmarkResumed);
    }


    private void OnBookmarkResumed(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object value)
    {
      if (value is PartnerSoftwareIntegrationStatus)
      {
        Status.Set(context, (PartnerSoftwareIntegrationStatus)value);
      }
    }

    protected override bool CanInduceIdle
    {
      get { return true; }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's weird. Your code seems just fine and is strange that you're getting an *InvalidCastException* after explicitly check if *value is PartnerSoftwareIntegrationStatus*.

Comment: *this was working fine before* - before what? How are you resuming the bookmark?

Comment: I think I found the explanation : the previous version of this activity did not include the OutArgument. The problem when resuming a workflow that was started using the old version and is resumed with the new version.

Comment: Jota: it was working before a version upgrade, which adds the OutArgument... I am resuming the bookmark the standard way, with the enum value as an argument.

Comment: Well, I guess you've found the problem then. Hopefully with WWF 4.5 we'll be able to solve some of these problems, with Workflow Versioning.

Comment: You've demonstrated the biggest WF4.0 problem with upgrading a workflow definition, which is that if any aspect of its surface area changes, persisted workflows won't be able to be sensibly resumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see these kinds of strange exceptions often when you make a change to a workflow definition and try to resume a persisted workflow.

Basically you can't make any changes to running workflows.